# Laravel Auth role_id session override just this session

Tags: laravel

is it possible to override a Auth session in Laravel, in the users table i have a column 'role_id' on the click if a button the role_id can change from 100 to 10, i have tried a few things but when the page reload i always end up with the role_id of 100, if i put the following at the top of the page

```
{{ Auth()->user()->role_id  }}  // role_id is 100 this is correct
```

if i put the following at the bottom of the page

```
{{ Auth()->user()->role_id = 20 }}  // role_id is 20 this is correct
```

When i reload the page the role_id is 100, can the role_id be overriden? i have used unset on the role_id first but its still not working, thank you

Comment: if the `role_id` is changing, why are you not updating it in the database?

Comment: The page reload will re-fetch the data from your auth session. So unless you actually save that 20 it will not persist. You would have to have some sort of work around. IE: setting a different variable in the session and checking that with the actual role_id.

Comment: its only for the one session when they log in again they will have a role_id of 100

Comment: @NMahurin Thank you, i have it working